# Useless use of LOOP_BLOCK_1 symbol in sink context

Tags: raku

With a snippet like

```
perl6 -e 'loop { FIRST say "foo"; last }'
```

I get

```
WARNINGS for -e:
Useless use of LOOP_BLOCK_1 symbol in sink context (line 1)
foo
```

I know how to work around the warning. I'm wondering about what the source of the warning is. I found [this open ticket](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/1900), but it doesn't seem to have received any attention.

What is this warning about?

And what about this is useless?

#### Version

```
$ perl6 --version
This is Rakudo version 2018.06 built on MoarVM version 2018.06
implementing Perl 6.c.
```

Comment: I think it's just a generic warning used for almost any error, this time telling you to use do loop

Comment: That doesn't tell me much, though. And FWIW, `perl6 -e 'do loop { FIRST say "foo"; last }'` gives me the same warning

Comment: Is this a first run? Do you have a .precomp?

Comment: I get the same result the no matter if it was the first time or not. About the .precomp, I'm not sure where to look for it. Where should it be if I had one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bug, a bogus warning.

> I know how to work around the warning.

That's the main thing.

> I'm wondering about what the source of the warning is.

It's a bogus warning from the compiler.

> I found this open ticket, but it doesn't seem to have received any attention.

I think it got some attention.

bbkr, who filed the bug, linked to another bug in which they showed their workaround. (It's not adding `do` but rather removing the `FIRST` phaser and putting the associated statement outside of the loop just before it.)

If you follow the other links in bbkr's original bug you'll arrive at another bug explaining that the general "unwanted" mechanism needs to be cleaned up. I imagine available [round tuits](https://szabgab.com/img/fosdem_2010_tuits.jpg) are focused on bigger fish such as this overall mechanism.

Hopefully you can see that it's just a bizarre warning message and a minor nuisance in the bigger scheme of things. It appears to come up if you use the FIRST phaser in a loop construct. It's got the very obvious work around which you presumably know and bbkr showed.

> What is this warning about?

Many languages allow you to mix procedural and functional paradigms. Procedural code is run for its side effects. Functional code for its result. Some constructs can do both.

But what if you use a construct that's normally used with the intent of its result being used, and the compiler knows that, but it also knows it's been used in a context in which its value will be ignored?

Perls call this "useless use of ... in sink context" and generally warn the coder about it. ("sink" is an alternative/traditional term for what is often called "void" context in other language cultures.)

This error message is one of these warnings, albeit a bogus one.

> And what about this is useless?

Nothing.

The related compiler warning mechanism has gotten confused.

The "Useless use of ... in sink context" part of the message is generic and hopefully self-explanatory.

But there's no way it should be saying things like "LOOP_BLOCK_1 symbol". That's internal mumbo-jumbo.

It's a warning message bug.